# How to make a JOptionPane appear at an attempt to close a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane

I am currently working on a Java application using a JFrame. What I want, is to have it when someone tries to close the window, it will make a JOptionPane appear asking: "Are you sure you want to exit 3DWorld?" and then have two buttons at the bottom saying Yes and No. Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for some basic information and some helper classes.